# How to specify compression level in spring boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot

How to specify compression level in a spring boot 2.0 application?

Options specified in documentation only allow you to enable/disable compression, specify mime-types and specify minimum response size.

Is it going to do compression at max-level i.e. level 9 for all responses?

Comment: I had same issue and resolved as follows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221225/how-to-specify-gzip-properties-in-spring-boot-2-application/71233349#71233349

Answer (score 1):

Try with:
**spring.http.gzip.deflate-compression-level= # the level used for deflate compression (0-9)**. Appendix:

```
 # HTTP response compression (GzipFilterProperties)
    spring.http.gzip.buffer-size= # size of the output buffer in bytes
    spring.http.gzip.deflate-compression-level= # the level used for deflate compression (0-9)
    spring.http.gzip.deflate-no-wrap= # noWrap setting for deflate compression (true or false)
    spring.http.gzip.enabled=true # enable gzip filter support
    spring.http.gzip.excluded-agents= # comma-separated list of user agents to exclude from compression
    spring.http.gzip.exclude-agent-patterns= # comma-separated list of regular expression patterns to control user agents excluded from compression
    spring.http.gzip.exclude-paths= # comma-separated list of paths to exclude from compression
    spring.http.gzip.exclude-path-patterns= # comma-separated list of regular expression patterns to control the paths that are excluded from compression
    spring.http.gzip.methods= # comma-separated list of HTTP methods for which compression is enabled
    spring.http.gzip.mime-types= # comma-separated list of MIME types which should be compressed
    spring.http.gzip.excluded-mime-types= # comma-separated list of MIME types to exclude from compression
    spring.http.gzip.min-gzip-size= # minimum content length required for compression to occur
    spring.http.gzip.vary= # Vary header to be sent on responses that may be compressed
```

Comment: Updated my question with proper spring boot version. These configs are not applicable to spring boot 2.0