# How to specify GZip properties in Spring boot 2 application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gzip

I have spring boot 2 application with REST API clients. There is a API to download large byte array (around 85MB), so I willing to compress it using GZip encoding. Added following properties to application.properties file

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=1024
server.compression.mime-types=application/octet-stream
```

Default compression reduce file size but it increase processing time rapidly. I saw there are compression levels in GZip encoding from 0-9.

How I set compression level in application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve my issue by changing embedded server to jetty.

First exclude embedded tomcat and add jetty dependency in pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Then add Custom `JettyServletWebServerFactory` as follows

```
@Configuration
public class GZipConfig {

    @Bean
    public JettyServletWebServerFactory jettyServletWebServerFactory() {
        JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addServerCustomizers((Server server) -> {
            GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
            gzipHandler.setInflateBufferSize(1);
            gzipHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
            gzipHandler.setIncludedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT");
            gzipHandler.setCompressionLevel(Deflater.BEST_SPEED);

            HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection(gzipHandler);
            server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
        });
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Here we can add compression level.

Thanks